# find all integer solution to $4x^2 + 51x \equiv 0 $ mod $101$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

what im trying is multiply both sides by 100,

$400x^2 + 5100x \equiv 0 $ mod $101$,

$-x^2 + 50x \equiv 0 $ mod $101$,

$x^2 - 50x \equiv 0 $ mod $101$,

$(x -25)^2 -625 \equiv 0 $ mod $101$,

$(x -25)^2 \equiv 19 $ mod $101$.

Then i have no idea how to find all integer solutions for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since your modulus is prime, you have $101 \mid 4x^2+51x = x(4x+51)$, so either $101 \mid x$ or $101 \mid 4x+51$.  That is, either $x\equiv 0 (\bmod{101})$ or $4x+51 \equiv 0 (\bmod{101})$.  Both are easy to solve, and this gives two solutions modulo $101.$